# Inheritance in Python - TypeError

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm trying to learn python syntax and I don't understand why the example below doesn't work. I get this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Code:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lastName = "Mustermann" 
        self.firstName = "Max"
    def get_name(self):
        return self.firstName+" "+self.lastName 
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.firstName = "Moritz"
        self.lastName=Parent.lastName
p=Parent()
c = Child(p)
print(c.get_name())
```

I also don't understand why Parent.lastName should work (according to what I read). Parent is a class, so why would it access the lastName of the instance?
What I really want is that Child inherits the lastName of Parent, but not the firstName.

Comment: `c = Child(p)` => `c = Child()`. You don't need an _instance_ to inherit from a class

Comment: Alternatively, a `Child` instance *has* a `Parent`, rather than *being* a `Parent`, in which case `Child` should not inherit from `Parent`, but instead `Child.__init__` should take an instance of `Parent` as an argument.

Comment: `Parent.lastName` doesn't work - `AttributeError: type object 'Parent' has no attribute 'lastName'` but it is stopping at your first error.

Comment: @chepner That would make more sense, but I was trying to learn inheritance, thats why I constructed it this way. But I could invent better names for that example, because maybe thats what unconsciously tricked my brain into wrinting Child(p).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c = Child(p)` is an error: the constructor doesn't take any argument except the `self` implicit one.

You don't need to copy `lastName` as `Child` inherits from `Parent`. But since you defined `__init__` in `Child` you have to call `Parent` `__init__` method as well for that (else parent constructor isn't called):

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lastName = "Mustermann"
        self.firstName = "Max"
    def get_name(self):
        return self.firstName+" "+self.lastName
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)
        self.firstName = "Moritz"

p=Parent()
c = Child()
print(c.get_name())
```

prints:

```
Moritz Mustermann
```

To call the parent `__init__` method we used

```
Parent.__init__(self)
```

we could also have used `super` like this:

```
super(Child,self).__init__()
```

which amounts to the same thing here (single inheritance), so even like:

```
super().__init__()
```

Comment: should'nt that be a `super(Parent,self).__init__()` call?

Comment: it doesn't work because it's `super(Child,self).__init__()` :)

Comment: Just plain `super().__init__()` would work (in Py3).

Comment: it does. Adopting that syntax from now. Worked too much with old 2.x python versions so `super` wasn't my friend...

Answer (score 1):

A child isn't (necessarily) a parent, it *has* a parent. Also, the names shouldn't be hard-coded in the `__init__` method, but passed as arguments. Not every instance of `Child` or `Person` will have the same names (although in this simple example, a child will share its parent's last name).

(I changed `Parent` to `Person` since there's nothing particularly parent-like about the `Parent` class. A `Child` still has a `Person` as a parent, though.)

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName):
        self.lastName = firstName
        self.firstName = lastName

    def get_name(self):
        return self.firstName+" "+self.lastName 


class Child(Person):
    def __init__(self, firstName, parent):
        super().__init__(firstName, parent.lastName)
        self.parent = parent

p = Person("Max", "Mustermann")
c = Child("Moritz", p)
print(c.get_name())
```

Comment: `c.get_name()` will no longer work... perhaps `Parent` and `Child` should inherit from `Person` and define `get_name()` in `Person`. And it does usually take 2 to tango :)

Comment: Yeah, I never bothered looking at `get_name` :)

Comment: (I may also have taken the `Child`/`Parent` names too literally, but at least now the answer demonstrates both inheritance and composition.)

Comment: @chepner You have taken them too literally, but your answer is still useful. I renamed Parent and Child into Person and Programmer. That makes my example much less confusing, which shows how important good variable names are. ;)